# Two different ways to train a neural network

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent, neural-networks

Gradient descent (GD) is a common algorithm designed to find a local minimum of an assigned cost function. Simple feedforward neural networks, as long as my understanding goes, try to estimate a minimum of an unknown function by minimizing a set of supposedly similar training functions, $f_1,\dots,f_k$. Each training function $f_i$ is a function of the network's parameters (weight and biases) and its shape/form depends on the training input $x_i$.

If I have $k$ training inputs and perform for each input $n$ GD steps, I could define my local minimum in two different ways:

1) For each input $x_i$, start at the same point $p_0$ in parameter space and then perform GD for $n$ steps. This gives $k$ "possible minimums", $p_1,\dots,p_k$ one for each input, then take as the "common minimum" their average: $\hat{p}:=\frac{1}{k}\sum p_i$.

2) Starting at the point $p_0$ in parameter space, perform $1$ GD step for each input $x_i$, resulting in new parameters $p_1^1,\dots,p_k^1$, then take their average as the next starting point: $p_1:=\frac{1}{k}\sum p_i^1$. Take another GD step for each input again, this time starting from $p_1$. Repeat $n$ times.

The two processes are represented below for a $2$-dimensional parameter space, $2$ inputs and $5$ GD steps:

[image: Two ways of optimizing a NN.]

The resulting "common minimum" is different in the two processes. This consderation leads to the study of a sort of "commutator" of many functions, which I'll represent with "$((f,g))$" and which for two functions looks like this:
\begin{equation}
\left(\left(\ f,g\right)\right):=
\frac{f(f(x))+g(g(x))}{2} - 
\frac{1}{2}\left[
f\left(\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}\right)+
g\left(\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}\right)
\right]
\end{equation}
The actual "commutator" for the GD is more complicated and involves the derivatives of the functions but it all boils down to the previous definition.

My question is: which, between the two procedures should be used to optimize a NN and why? And is this "commutator" something that is actually studied somewhere?

Comment: Isn't it true that when we train a feedforward neural network we simply minimize one single objective function which is completely known to us? We can minimize the objective function using gradient descent or any other optimization algorithm that we like (such as stochastic gradient descent or some variant thereof). It's important to distinguish conceptually between the optimization problem and the optimization method that we use to solve the optimization problem.

Comment: I don't think that the objective function is known. For instance, for the MNIST dataset, one has a different cost function for each hand written digit. The NN gets optimized for an "overall average hand written digit" which is not known beforehand...or not?

Comment: I think there is one single objective function that quantifies how well our neural network does at classifying all digits in the training dataset. It would be possible to write down this objective function explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure? Say the function is $f=\sum(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2$ where $y_i$ are the calculated outputs and $\hat{y}_i$ are the desired outputs. Then $f$ would depend on the inputs and so be different from input to input. We would then optimize for this particular function for each input and then average out. The averaging is done to optimize for *another* function which is actually unknown.

Comment: Maybe you could expand your thoughts in an answer with a simple example to make me understand?

Comment: What are the inputs to the function $f$ that you've written? I think perhaps it would clarify things to write or describe the inputs to $f$ explicitly.

Comment: Let $x_k$ be the NN inputs ($x_k$ represents the $k$-th training set) $y$ the outputs, $\hat{y}$ the desired outputs  and $W_{ij}$ and $b_m$ the weights and biases. Then $f(y,\hat{y})=\tilde{f}(y(x_k,W_{ij},b_m),\hat{y})=f_k(W_{ij},b_m)$

Comment: So in the MNIST example each vector $x_k$ represent a handwritten digit, if I understand your notation. The neural network objective function that we minimize involves summing over all values of $k$. Something like $F(W,b) = \sum_k f_k(W,b)$. The fact that we are minimizing a sum of a large number of functions $f_k$ makes it tempting to use stochastic gradient descent, but we don't have to. We could simply minimize $F$ using gradient descent.

Comment: yes, exactly. Each handwritten digit tends to optimize the NN towards self-recognition. We don't want that, since we need a more general classifier. We would like to use a "universal handwritten digit" but we don't know its shape (or even if it exists or if it's unique)

Comment: If we minimize $F(W,b) = \sum_k f_k(W,b)$ using stochastic gradient descent, it might lead to the kind of averaging you're thinking of. But stochastic gradient descent is only one of many possible optimization algorithms.

Comment: I'm still not convinced that your function $F$ is actually what we're minimizing...

Comment: By the way, is there a particular book or article you're reading to learn this topic?

Comment: actually not really...All stems from 3blue1brown's video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk

Comment: Hmm, those are good videos but 3blue1brown doesn't seem to write the full objective function explicitly. Textbooks do write the full objective function explicitly, on the other hand. Check out equation (6) here, for example: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html (This is Michael Nielsen's Neural Networks and Deep Learning book.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you mean with "supposedly similar functions".

At a very basic level training a neural net $f_\theta$ with parameters $\theta$ is done by minimisation of the empirical risk, i.e. the best approximation we have to the true risk (of misclassification for mnist) since we do not know the distribution of the data $(X,Y)$. If $\mathbf{x}$ are the inputs and $\mathbf{y}$ their labels, this is simply

$$ L_\theta(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \sum_i l(f_\theta(x_i), y_i) $$

with e.g. $l(\xi,y) = \| \xi - y \|^2$ or any other loss function. Instead of performing gradient descent, i.e. optimising (for $\theta$) this sum over *all* training samples, one typically does stochastic GD, i.e. over one or a few samples. The expected value of this stochastic gradient is the gradient and as long as the learning rate fulfils some conditions (e.g. the classical "$\sum \alpha_t = \infty$ but $\sum \alpha_t^2 \le \infty$ ") this converges and is not only computationally cheaper but tends to exhibit better behaviour than vanilla GD.

If I understand you correctly, this is basically your 2. since "performing one GD step for each point and averaging" is by linearity the same as computing the gradient of the whole sum, then updating once the parameters, as long as you don't change update the parameters after each point. If you do, then that is SGD, but no average should be taken at the end (why would that make sense?)

Your 1. is a bit strange to me since it seems that would basically try to overfit to each sample, i.e. to learn $\theta_i$ such that $f_{\theta_i}(x_i)$ is as close to $y_i$ as possible, and this is unlikely to produce a good global solution, let alone generalise out of the training set.